# Read Date Value from TextBox and Convert to Month and Year

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a text-box in a detailview and the value of the text-box is a Date but it only shows the Month and Year and it is like this:November 2013  so i want to take this value and convert like this: 20131101.  So as you can see, i would like the format to be YYYYMMDD but the day should always be 01 which is the first of the month.  So how can i go from this November 2013 to this 20131101?  here is my code and i know i have to convert from string to date first:

```
string myDate = ((TextBox)DetailView1.FindControl("InputDate")).Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you need to retain it as a DateTime field? Or just a string?

Comment: i am going to take the value and insert into table but the data type for the column is float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it:

```
TextBox txtInputDate = (TextBox)DetailView1.FindControl("InputDate");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtInputDate.Text, "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then  convert it to string again:

```
txtInputDate.Text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There is no need for the setting of the `DateTime` object to the first of the month, as the default value for `Day` is 1 and the time is set to 12:00:00 AM by default as well.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: That's true, the `InputDate` has confused me somehow.

Comment: thanks Tim, i am getting this error: Failed to convert parameter value from a TextBox to a String

Comment: First, if you are passing a date-parameter to a `SqlCommand` you should not use a `String` but a `DateTime`. So no need to convert  it back to string. Second, if you really need a string, why are you using a `TextBox` instead of `TextBox.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

C# is pretty good at parsing stringy dates, you could lean on the build it parsing:

```
string myDateString = ((TextBox)DetailView1.FindControl("InputDate")).Text.ToString();
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(myDateString, out myDate)) {
    // myDate now contains a proper .NET date.
}
```

Now you have a proper DateTime, you can output it in any format you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Parse("November 2013");
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method, like this:

```
var theParsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "MMMM yyyy", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can use the parsed date however you wish, convert it to string, send it to database, etc.